# Creating a multiplying function

Tags: python, function, multiplication

I don't understand how to make a function and then make it work which will allow me to multiply. 
For E.g.

```
def Multiply(answer):
    num1,num2 = int(2),int(3) 
    answer = num1 * num2
    return answer

print(Multiply(answer))
```

I Had a go at making one and didnt work so the one below is where i found on internet but i have no idea how to make it work as in print out the numbers timed.

```
def multiply( alist ):
     theproduct = 1
     for num in alist: theproduct *= num
     return theproduct
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you have your parameter as your return value and you want your paramters to be inputs to your function. So try

```
def Multiply(num1, num2):
    answer = num1 * num2
    return answer

print(Multiply(2, 3))
```

As for the second script, it looks fine to me. You can just print the answer to the console, like so (notice it takes a list as an argument)

```
print multiply([2, 3])
```

Just know that the second script will multiply numbers in the list cumulatively.

Answer (score 6):

It's easier than you thought

```
from operator import mul

mul(2,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this a little easier and simpler?

```
def multiply(a,b):
    return a*b

print(multiply(2,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `*` (which I'm guessing you don't), you can do this:

```
def multiply(x, y):
    a = 0
    x2 = int(x)
    y2 = int(y)
    for i in range(y2):
        a += x2
    return a
print(multiply(2,4))
```

but I recommend using `*` since its easier than this ^

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
def Multiply( num1, num2 ): 
    answer = num1 * num2
    return answer

print(Multiply(2, 3))
```

The function Multiply will take two numbers as arguments, multiply them together, and return the results. I'm having it print the return value of the function when supplied with 2 and 3. It should print 6, since it returns the product of those two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
def numbermultiplier(num1, num2): 
      ans = num1 * num2 
      return ans
```

and then call function like

`print(numbermultiplier(2,4))`

Answer (score 0):

Is that actually what you needed?

```
 def multiple(number, multiplier, *other):
    if other:
        return multiple(number * multiplier, *other)
    return number * multiplier
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you want to multiply without using "*"

```py
def multiply(x, y):
    x = int(inp1)
    y2 = int(inp2)
    y = 1
    x2 = x
    while y < y2:
        x2 += x
        y += 1
    print(x2)
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiplying n numbers you can use eval

```
def multiply(*nums):
   return eval('*'.join(nums))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def Multiply(a, b): 
    answer = a * b
    return answer

print(Multiply(2, 3))
```